# Could baryon asymmetry be negative?

Tags: baryogenesis

In the paper http://hamilton.uchicago.edu/~harvey/pdf_files/harvey_turner_1990.pdf,
it can be seen from expressions (9a, 9b,9c) that barygon asymmetry is proportional to negative lepton asymmetry. But in a model where leptogensis is generated and L >0, we get negative B. But this contradicts observation. Many papers I read seem not to elaborate on this point.

I am confused about this result and interpretation.

Comment: Do you mean that $B$ is proportional to $-L$?

Comment: @ Luc J. Bourhis Yes, as somehow seen in the paper.

Comment: Your remark holds good below the critical temperature too: eq (11). And the first equation on p. 42 has again L and B of opposite signs. I have only vague recollections about that physics: I will read the paper thoroughly.